# Callout accessory button displayed, but invisible

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a map in my app which display some POI for my own project. I'm not using the default red pin but decided to make my own one. This pin works and looks fine and when I click on it I get the callout bubble but it's not showing the default accessorybutton on the right. It does, however, show empty space indicating that it's there and if I change it from the right to the left, it does actually move but I can't see it.

[image: The whitespace is where the button is normally]

As you can see my bubble is clearly making room for the button and when I click where the button is supposed to be it will actually run my

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
```

without any problems so the accessory button is just 'hidden'.

This is the code that I have for the default annotation view:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView {
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"PlaceAnnotation"];

annotationView.enabled = YES;
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationPin"];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -annotationView.image.size.height / 2);

return annotationView;
```

}

And this is the code in my MapViewController itself:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceAnnotation class]]) {

    PlaceAnnotation *placeAnnotation = (PlaceAnnotation *)annotation;

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"PlaceAnnotation"];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = placeAnnotation.annotationView;
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

}

Am I wrong into thinking that the

```
.rightCalloutAccessoryView = ...
```

Is the only line I need to make the button show? I just want the default blue circle with an i in the middle next to my text so it's clear to my users that they can click on the bubble.

S.

Comment: Are you setting tintColor anywhere in the app (like for UIButton appearance)?

Comment: I have no references to tintColor in my code. However, your comment made me wonder if I could change the tintColor of my annotationView to be blue to see if the tintColor was indeed causing the problem (and since I'd only apply it to my annotationView it wouldn't influence anything else) and guess what... Problem solved! Please re-write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why your accessory button is "invisible" but the standard `UIButton`s are affected by the `tintColor` setting.

Try explicitly setting the `tintColor` on the annotation view:

```
annotationView.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

The tintColor didn't work for me, so after some playing around I got this to work.

The trick was setting a frame for the image. The detail disclosure button works because it has a set size already:

```
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"directionArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
    pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
```